# use nutch to index my local HTML files

Tags: indexing, nutch, local-files

I have a lot of HTML files on my hard disk and want to index them with Nutch, but as I know nutch only get URLs and index them and pages that linked in that URLs.
Does any body know how can I use nutch to index my local files??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post;
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FAQ#How_do_I_index_my_local_file_system.3F